# what's the right way to create a nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, nested-forms

i'm creating a blog system with RoR 3.2.8 and Mongoid. I have two related models: Post and Comment ("posts has many comments").

In action "show" of the controller PostController I need to add a form to insert new comments, right? Can I do the code below?

```
<% form_for Comment.new do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_area :text  %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => @post.id  %>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

If I can't do, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer on this post, [How can I include form elements from other objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571845/how-can-i-include-form-elements-from-other-objects/11571931#11571931).  Basically, you're going to need to use fields_for.